# Luarocks fails installing 'async' & 'trepl' [Error: Connection timed out]

Tags: lua, luarocks

Hello fellow programmers,

I'm new to the Lua world. I'm working with [this application](https://github.com/DmitryUlyanov/texture_nets) and I constantly end up receiving the following error while trying to run the code following their README:

```
/usr/bin/luajit: /usr/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:383: module 'display' not found:No LuaRocks module found for display
        no field package.preload['display']
        no file '/tmp/buildd/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/display.lua'
        no file '/tmp/buildd/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/display/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/display.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/display/init.lua'
        no file './display.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta1/display.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/display.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/display/init.lua'
        no file '/gpfs01/bethge/home/hmoriceau/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/display.lua'
        no file '/gpfs01/bethge/home/hmoriceau/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/display/init.lua'
        no file '/tmp/buildd/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/display.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/display.so'
        no file './display.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/display.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
        no file '/gpfs01/bethge/home/hmoriceau/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/display.so'
     stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        /usr/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:383: in function 'require'
        stylization_train.lua:9: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'dofile'
        /usr/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:145: in main chunk
        [C]: at 0x00406670
```

Naturally I tried to run a `sudo luarocks install display` but get the following error:

```
Installing https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/display-scm-0.rockspec...
Using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/display-scm-0.rockspec... switching to 'build' mode

Missing dependencies for display:
async >= 1.0
luasocket >= 2.0

Using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/async-scm-1.rockspec... switching to 'build' mode
Cloning into 'async'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.253.113]: errno=Connection timed out


Error: Failed installing dependency: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/async-scm-1.rockspec - Failed cloning git repository.
```

Some people have had [similar errors](https://github.com/torch/distro/issues/15) but I think the source of this one is different. I also think that it is unlikely that the mirror for this module is down.

Lua version: 5.2.3
Installed using `sudo apt-get install lua5.2` after having updated&&upgraded everything.

Your help is appreciated!

Best,

Hichame

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who had this issue, I managed to solve it using: `git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/`

For documentation, you might also be interested in knowing that you can manually install lua modules using:

```
git clone <module-repo>
cd <module-repo-directory>
sudo luarocks make
```